# I need a software distribution platform

Tags: web, software-distribution

Alright so I am making some small applications and I would like to host a website to distribute them.

For now I'd be giving my programs away for free but later I plan to sell some of them for a small price.

To do this I'd need a website, I have the hosting I have the domain but I don't have the web software, and I'd like some recommendations on which software to use.

First I tried joomla, but that's no good because it's annoying to manage and doesn't allow tracking the amount of downloads.

Then I tried magneto, which is good but it doesn't seem to allow instant downloading for free software (users have to go through the checkout process).

Then I thought maybe i'll just use like google code or something, would be great to also manage my source code, but that only allows open-source software

So yeah, any recommendations are welcome

tl;dr: I need a platform to distribute my software on which can track downloads and allows users to quickly download software

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. Web hosting with downloads? Not really a programming question.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if you had explore interesting distribution platforms such as [OptimumInstaller](http://optimuminstaller.net/publishers/).  Now there are some focusing on mobile apps also, apart from the notorious Playstore.

Comment: the link for optimum installer is dead. And the first page of google mostly mentions it as a Virus.